# Laravel pagination won't re-initialize MySQL variables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I have this query:

```
select 
    id,
    @product_rank := IF(@current_category = category_id, @product_rank + 1, 1) AS product_rank,
    @current_category := category_id
from products
```

And create a query using Eloquent builder:

```
Products::from(DB::raw('
    (select 
        id,
        @product_rank := IF(@current_category = category_id, @product_rank + 1, 1) AS product_rank,
        @current_category := category_id
    from products) as q 
'))->where('product_rank', '<=', 10)->paginate(5);
```

Because Laravel pagination wants to get the total count of all records, it executes an extra query like this:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from (
    select 
        id,
        @product_rank := IF(@current_category = category_id, @product_rank + 1, 1) AS product_rank,
        @current_category := category_id
    from products 
) q where product_rank <= 10
```

So `@current_category` and `@product_rank` won't re-initialize and the main query returns wrong results.

I wonder if there is way to re-initialize both variables.

Comment: See e.g. [MySql : Initialize mySql variable inside a query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40279318/6248528)

Comment: @Solarflare Very nice idea. It works.